# Prove $f(x) \in (c,d)$ for all $x$ in an interval.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}, f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and $f(x) \in (c,d)$ for all $x \in S \subset [a,b]$ where $S$ is not a measure zero set. **Show** that there exists some interval $(a',b')$ such that $f(x) \in (c,d)$ for all $x\in (a', b')$.

Definitions:

Riemann integrable implies $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists$partition $P_\epsilon$ so that $U(P_\epsilon, f) - L(P_\epsilon, f) < \epsilon$ for all Riemann sums.

Non measure zero implies $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall \{(a_k,b_k)\}_1^\infty$ whose union covers $S$ gives $\sum_1^{\infty} b_k - a_k \geq \epsilon$

I'm not sure how to go about this proof. I didn't know a set of positive (nonzero) measure could not contain intervals. Can someone please offer some advice?

Edit: I'm thinking perhaps we can do this by contradiction. Suppose $S$ contains no intervals (i.e. it's a set of discrete points) then show $f$ is not Riemann integrable or $S$ is measure zero...

Comment: I realized that my answer was wrong because the wording confused me. I've deleted my answer and edited your post to make it harder for someone to make the same mistake I did (as apparently two others did).

Comment: Sorry about that. I see where the confusion was.

Answer (score 2):

By Lebesgue's integrability condition, $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$. In particular, there exists $x_0\in S$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. Choose $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(f(x_0)-\varepsilon,f(x_0)+\varepsilon)\subset(c,d)$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-x_0|<\delta,$ $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. The desired interval is $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.